# Java new values return after remove

Tags: java, arrays, return

A little bit explanation about code: `ntTPla.values()` contains Plans and inside some Plans can have Packages ( child's ). There are code, which adding Packages to Plans "ntTPla.addPackage". After this code ( when all packages will be added to Plans ) I should check Packages and delete wrong Packages. I wrote code, which checking if Packages is good and remove wrong ones. Question - how to return all Plans and new Packages near them? Because now code returning old ones. I debugged and removing working fine, just need to fix return. How my code should look like?

```
[...]
        List<Plan> tPlan = new ArrayList<Plan>();
        tPlan.addAll(ntTPla.values());
        
        List<Packet> packetFirst = new ArrayList<Packet>();
        packetFirst.addAll(tPlan.get(0).getPacket());
        
        String test2 = null;
            for (int i = 0 ; i < packetFirst.size(); i++){ 
                if(packetFirst.get(i).getBest()) {
                    test2 = packetFirst.get(i).getCode();
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            for (int ii =  packetFirst.size() - 1 ; ii >= 0; ii--){ 
                if(!packetFirst.get(ii).getCode().equals(test2)) {
                    packetFirst.remove(ii);
                }
            }
        
        return ntTPla.values();
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe it seems that the problem is that the value returned by the statement of `return ntTPla.values();` still contains packets that were removed. You remove the item from `packetFirst`, but not from `ntPla.values()`. You will just need to do something like

```
for (int ii =  packetFirst.size() - 1 ; ii >= 0; ii--){ 
    if(!packetFirst.get(ii).getCode().equals(test2)) {
        packetFirst.remove(ii);
        ntPla.values().remove(ii);
    }
}
```

EDIT

After discussing the problem in the comment section, maybe I have a better understanding about the problem than previously. This is my suggested solution:

```
for (int planIndex = 0; planIndex < tPlan.size(); planIndex++) {
    Plan plan = tPlan.get(planIndex);
    int bestIndex = 0;
    for (int packetIndex = 0; packetIndex < plan.getPacket().size(); packetIndex++) {
        Packet packet = plan.getPacket().get(packetIndex);
        if (packet.getBest()) bestIndex = packetIndex;
    }
    if (bestIndex >= 0) plan.getPacket.remove(bestIndex);
}
```

It's possible that I still do not understand the problem. If that's the case, then please excuse me.

Comment: I tried to use this code and I getting warning message: "Unlikely argument type int for remove(Object) on a Collection<Plan>". ntTPla.values() - conains Plans, Packages inside this. We need to remove Packages, which is deeper inside.

Comment: @yYy then you can iterate your `values` and remove from packages what needs to be removed.

Comment: Maybe you can show me how it will looks like? I'm newbie, so it difficult to get it.

Comment: @yYy can you share the code of your classes? `tPlan.get(0).getPacket()` is a big clue, but I would like to know more about the structure of your data.

Comment: There a lot lines of code in this class, so I don't know if it good to paste it here. But there nothing special about Packet's in that code. `tPlan.get(0).getPacket()` I will try explain this. `ntTPla.values()` contains Plans and Packages (childs of Plans). I created `tPlan` which contains 3 Plans ( 0,1,2 index ) and `packetFirst` which contains all Packages of first Plan (0 index). So with this code I try to get all Packages of first Plan. Later I check all Packages and remove them from List. Removing from List working fine, just need to figure out how to return Collection.

Comment: @yYy I'm happy to provide you a proper answer, but I need the parts of your code relevant to this question. You could paste all the code separately, or you could just extract the relevant parts of it. Earlier I have made an assumption to answer your question which turned out to be inaccurate. Instead of risking another inaccuracy with another assumption on my part I kindly ask you to provide more details about your question. Also, I see you have accepted my answer. Was it helpful in resolving your problem at the end?

Comment: I edited my post and added some more code. Maybe now is more clear for you? Your answer is good, because you right, I should figure out return. `packetFirst` is returning good Packages, but I need to return in whole code Plans + new Packages attached to Plans.

Comment: Maybe it will better to change my `remove` code to for example `filter`? Maybe just need to realize this by another way? But I don't know how to..

Comment: @yYy `Map<DbPlanCategory, Plan> ntTPla = new HashMap<>();` provides an important clue about what ntTPla is. `packetFirst.addAll(tPlan.get(0).getPacket());` generates all packets from the first plan from tPlan into packetFirst. So, packetFirst is the packets of the first plan. You are removing the packets from the newly created copies of plans and packets, but not from the originals. So there are two problems to solve: 1) you need to remove the packets from the original, rather than a copy, doing a copy here seems to be unnecessary and 2) You do not return the packets. Editing my answer.

Comment: Thank you for answer. You right, that my old code have no sense. I tried your new solution and have some problems. `plan.getPacket().get(packetIndex);` when I try add this line, I have error, because `plan.getPacket().` don't have `.get`. Error: The method get(int) is undefined for the type Collection<Plan>. Also in line `if (packetIndex >= 0) plan.getPacket.remove(packetIndex);` I have error: `packetIndex cannot be resolved to a variable`. I will be very happy If you will help me with this.

Comment: @yYy thanks for your reply. The second problem you pointed out was actually a typo on my part, which is now fixed. The problem was that instead removing the packet at the bestIndex (which was the point of the cycle), my old code attempted to remove an item at an index that no longer exists :) Fixed it. As about the first problem, my code assumed that getPacket returns a List of packets. If that assumption is incorrect, then I need to find out what the type of getPacket is. This kind of questions prompted me earlier into asking for the class codes. So, the second problem you pointed out was

Comment: @yYy a mistake from me, while the second problem you have pointed out is probably also a mistake, but without knowing the definitions we are working with it's difficult to avoid mistakes. So, again, I need the definition of getPacket :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//return ntTPla.values();

tPlan.set(0, packetFirst);
return tPlan;
```

Replace last line with above. You created `tPlan` so that you can safely modify a copy of plans independent of the original list of plans in `ntTPla.values()`. You need to replace plan `0` of `tPlan` with your newly processed `packetFirst`. Then return `tPlan`.

**Update**:
My earlier code was wrong.

```
final Plan newPlan = new Plan();
// newPlan.setPackage(packetFirst);
// Used a wrong setter name earlier.
newPlan.setPacket(packetFirst);
tPlan.set(0, newPlan);
return tPlan;
```

Is `tPlan` of type `java.util.List`?
[.set(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-)

**Update 2**:

```
for (int ii =  packetFirst.size() - 1 ; ii >= 0; ii--){ 
    if(!packetFirst.get(ii).getCode().equals(test2)) {
        packetFirst.remove(ii);
    }
}
// After your code above...

final Plan newPlan = new Plan();
//...
```

---

```
// I am guessing you have a class like this...
public class Plan {
    private List<Packet> packet;

    public void setPacket(List<Packet> packet) {
        this.packet = packet;
    }
    // getter here...
}
```

Comment: In my case tPlan don't have .set(). When I try to write "tPlan." , .set won appears.

Comment: `tPlan` is `java.util.List` all is good, sorry. It have `.set`. Where I should put `final Plan newPlan = new Plan();` line? What is `setPackage`?

Comment: `setPackage` should be `setPacket`. Sorry for the mistake. I have updated solution above.

Comment: Thank you for trying help me. I updated my first post ( added some code ). I don't have `public class Plan`. Can you check one more time my code?

Comment: Maybe it will better to change my `remove` code to for example `filter`? Maybe just need to realize this by another way? But I don't know how to..